# Append elements to a key in dictionary without overwriting the existing elements in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

If I have a dictionary as

```
dict = {"A": ["a", "b", "c"], "B": ["c", "d", "e"]}
```

I am wondering how could I get the dictionary as

```
dict = {"A": ["a", "b", "c", "w", "x", "y", "z"], "B": ["c", "d", "e"]}
```

I know the following code works but I am wondering if there is any easy way:

```
dict.setdefault("A", []).append("w")
dict.setdefault("A", []).append("x")
dict.setdefault("A", []).append("y")
dict.setdefault("A", []).append("z")
```

Thanks!

Comment: OK so it seems like the dict is irrelevant. Really you're asking how to add multiple items to a list at the same time -- which you can do with `list.extend`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the key in the dict, then either append a single item to the list or extend a new list:

```
dict["A"].extend(["w", "x", "y", "z"])
```

Comment: I got an error as: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extend'

Comment: @guoyili Sounds like you missed the closing bracket here: `"A"].extend`